# Does file_get_contents require --with_curl to access HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Does the `file_get_contents` require `--with_curl` to access `HTTP/HTTPS`?

Checking the `php.net` didn't seem to be clear, I'd like to know if I can get away with the `--with_curl`option.

Comment: [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) has no option called `with_curl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) has no option called `with_curl`